# Child div doesn't follow the width of parent with display:table

Tags: html, css

I try to recreate a css design to learn how to use the style: `display:table`. However, I have a problem which I cannot solve. The child div doesn't follow the width of the parent.

I have created a JSFiddle since the code is a lot.

The `pricetable` class follow the width of the window, but the `priceTableMain` doesn't. I tried to change the width from 100% to auto, but it didn't solve it.

Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5duhf8te/)

Comment: Six level of nested `div`, somethings really wrong with your markup structuring...

Comment: Yeah, I don't get what you're trying to do, the pricing table looks good. Mr. Alien has a point, you have a lot of nested divs, this code can be simplified. Try this tool to help you create a good table and a good code: https://coveloping.com/tools/pricing-tables

Comment: If the problem is that the table cells can't go narrower than about 112 pixels, that's right, because their contents are that wide. How do you want to solve it? Do you want some of the content to be hidden? You can go _somewhat_ narrower by adding spaces to the `15€/player` things, which would allow them to word wrap, but that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know your problem. Your markup isn't good but you are adding `width: 100%;`
you also need to place `table-layout: fixed;`

```
.priceTableMain {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
```